# Lifting étale sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic

Let $X$ be a scheme, $F$ and $G$ be sheaves in groups on $X$ for the étale topology and $f:F\rightarrow G$ a morphism of group sheaves. Assume that there exists an étale covering $i:U\rightarrow X$ such that the pullback $i^{*}f:i^{*}F\rightarrow i^{*}G$ admits a section, can I lift this section to a section of $f:F\rightarrow G$?

Answer (score 4):

Not in general, no.

(By the way, I would write "descend" rather than "lift"; you are trying to pass  from a property holding locally on the cover $U$ to a property over all of $X$.)

To fix ideas, suppose that $G = \mathbb Z/n,$ the constant sheaf attached to a cyclic group of order $n$, that $F$ also has exponent $n$,
and that that $F \to G$ is a surjective morphism.  Then by definition of surjectivity for sheaves, we may find an etale cover $U$ of $X$ such that
the section $1$ of $G$ lifts to a section of $F$ over $U$, and this provides a splitting of $F_{| U } \to G_{| U}$ (since this lift also has order $n$, by our assumption on the exponent of $F$).   But the original surjection $F \to G$ need not be split.

E.g. Any non-trivial extension of $\mathbb Z/n$ by $\mathbb Z/n$ as a $\mathbb Z/n$-sheaf will give such a non-split extension, and such extensions are computed by the etale cohomology group $H^1(X,\mathbb Z/n)$, which need not vanish in general.